# Gson class not found when running android app

Tags: android, gson, classnotfound

I have some problems about Gson import in my project

if I dependency like this:

`compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'`

The compile is OK,but when I run my app, it has bean crashed,such as
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qe4c5.jpg)

I try to dump the apk and analyze it, I found there is Gson in the dex,but runtime crash.

but when I download the gson.jar and put it into libs then make the dependency like this:

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

it fully worked.

and I don't know why ?
so help me.

sincerely!!!

Comment: Seems like you'r app needs MultiDex and you didn't enable it

Comment: Firstly, I enabled my multidex,but still crash,and there is only one dex in the apk. so maybe not multidex problem.and I have tried many mays to config multidex,but my apk still have only one dex .