# Android library with dependencies

Tags: android, android-library

I built an SDK for a project that needs Gson to function in order to serialize and deserialize complicated requests and responses from the backend. When I add my library as an AAR file in a test application I get this error when it tries to run: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/gson/Gson.` It goes away if I add a Gson dependency to my test application. My library gradle file looks like:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
}
```

but it seems just putting the dependency there is insufficient. What do I need to do in my library to make it so other users of my sdk don't have to add that as an additional dependency?

Comment: Distribute it as an artifact through a repository. An AAR, like a JAR, has no concept of dependencies. An artifact in a repository does, as it combines the actual content (the AAR) with metadata (e.g., a Maven-style POM file) that contains the dependency information.

Comment: That makes sense I guess. I guess that means it is impossible to include a dependency in an AAR file. Do you know if there is a way to for me to compile gson with my AAR since it's only a single dependency and it wouldn't make my library too large?

Comment: "I guess that means it is impossible to include a dependency in an AAR file" -- in a bare file? Correct. Moreover, publishing via a repository is a very good idea in general. For example, it handles versioning better than a bare AAR. "Do you know if there is a way to for me to compile gson with my AAR..." -- what happens when the user of your library wants to use Gson, but needs a different version? By publishing your AAR via a repository, they can manage this via Gradle. By baking Gson into your AAR, you're telling them they cannot use your AAR, or that they have to use your Gson.

Comment: Thank you for your insight here. You are always very helpful. I'll research how to securely publish it as an artifact on a repository.

Comment: I have the same problem, do you solve it?
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44851150/gson-class-not-found-when-running-android-app)